# SSLEOFError on FTPS using Python ftplib

Tags: python, ftplib, ftps

I'm connecting to an FTP site using FTPS (explicit). Connecting and basic commands work just fine, yet when I try to retrieve a directory listing or a file I get an SSLEOFError.

```
from ftplib import FTP_TLS
ftps = FTP_TLS()
ftps.auth()
ftps.prot_p()
ftps.login(username, password)
ftps.cwd('/')
ftps.retrlines('LIST')
ftps.quit()
```

Everything up to the 'LIST' command executes without problems. For the 'LIST' command I get the reply:

```
'150 Opening data channel for directory listing of "/"
```

And then I get the error:

```
SSLEOFError: EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:645)
```

I've tried setting TLSv1 explicitly - to no avail. Using an FTP client I can connect to the FTP site without problems. What am I doing wrong in my code? I've tried both Python 3.5 and 2.7.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem was that the FTP server I was connecting to requires session resumption, which isn't supported in Python 3.5 and 2.7. The functionality has been added in 3.6.